# Attempt to present modal VC on VC whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, modalviewcontroller, segue

I have a storyboard that looks like this:

[image: Storyboard]

This is how it works: the `InitialSlidingViewController` instantiates the Navigation VC as the `topViewController` as follows in its .m file:

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Navigation"];

}
```

After the Navigation VC gets instantiated, it creates the underlying Menu and sets that as the underLeftVC. This is using [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController). This creates a sliding menu that uses a pan gesture, similar to Facebook.

The rootVC for the NavigationVC is my ItemsCDTVC. When I click the + button, it pops up an action sheet that allows me to take a photo from the camera or choose from the photo library. However, I then want it to modally segue to the ManageItemVC and set the picture I just chose/took to its UIImageView. When I try to present, it throws the following error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <ManageItemViewController: 0x81d52a0> on <InitialSlidingViewController: 0x8122ce0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Which is true, because InitialSlidingVC is not on screen, ItemCDTVC is, but how do I fix this?

I have set the modal type segue in my Storyboard with an identifier from the flexible space at the bottom (when tapped, it doesn't do anything, so I chose that to create a visual segue). This is my segue code in ItemCDTVC:

```
 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // let's get the edited image
    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    // but if for some reason we disable editing in the future, this is our safeguard
    if(!image) image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    if(image) {
        self.pictureImageView.image = image;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addItemSegue" sender:self];
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addItemSegue"]){
        ManageItemViewController *manageItemVC = (ManageItemViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        manageItemVC.pictureImageView = self.pictureImageView;
    }
}
```

It fails when trying to present the modal VC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed, the only thing I had to do is dismiss the imagePickerController before trying to perform the segue, as so:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // let's get the edited image
    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    // but if for some reason we disable editing in the future, this is our safeguard
    if(!image) image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    if(image) {
        self.pictureImage = image;
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addItemSegue" sender:self];
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Not only after the dismissal but in the completion block.